# Need help finding the right transistor for a switching circuit

Tags: transistors, laser-driver

I have been doing much research to learn about transistors and to find the right resistor/transistor coupling to power a laser driver that I am building. I want to complete the circuit through the 5V/40mA output on an Arduino, as the base, to turn the laser on and off. The circuit will have between 0.2A and 1.25A current flowing through it to power the laser and that will either flow or be cut off by the transistor (the laser driver does not measure voltage, only current.) I want to use the NPN transistor as a switch so it will saturate completely.

Any help with the resistor and transistor I am looking for? I am having so much trouble reading through these data sheets. :/

Here is an image of the laser driver diagram for those who requested!
[image: Circuit Diagram for laser driver]

Comment: It may help if you post a schematic that shows how you are imagining the circuit will look.

Comment: To minimize the power lost in the transistor, I'd strongly recommend you consider using a MOSFET instead of a BJT.

Comment: Indeed i'm with @ThePhoton on this, use a MOSFET to act as the switch. Definitely provide us with a schematic/diagram of how you want to drive this laser, because we may be able to point out flaws/things to save you time and more strange questions later ;)

Comment: Schematic looks good. make sure when you put the FET or transistor in the low side switch like that, or even in general, put a pull down (10k will work fine, 100k if you wanted) resistor to avoid floating pins on the arduino when powered off or not set as output yet. You do not want a bird's fart 30 meters away to turn on the laser and turn the bird into cooked lunch!

Comment: Looks decent, but a few comments: 1) Like everyone else mentioned, consider a FET instead of a BJT.  You won't have to worry about base current because there isn't any; it's driven by voltage instead.  And you'll waste less power in the transistor.  2) Interesting current source.  No problems for constant DC, but you're switching this on and off.  How does the 338 behave in that case?

Comment: (continued)  3) Lots of power wasted in the resistors.  You might want to consider a different design just for that reason.  4) The only reason to need a reverse diode is for reverse polarity protection or inductive flyback EMF.  You probably don't have either one, so you can delete it.

Comment: Indeed be very careful of the resistors in series with the output, the 1A may cause hilarious hot little heaters. That is your attempt at current limiting? Perhaps a proper current limiting solution should be found, seeing as you intend to go into the amps range. I suggest an op-amp feedback with sense resistor, along with the N channel MOSFET as the low side swithc. The potentiometer can still act as a "power tuner" but this time it's the comparison point for the Opamp to ground the MOSFET, acting as a hardware current limit

Comment: I agree with @AaronD you don't really need the reverse diode, as far as I can tell

Comment: Why the "bleep" are you driving the LED with 12 Volts?  Is it a string or a single LED? (I hate the pot in the high current line, just solder in different resistors, or use a switch with different R's)

Comment: I'd be tempted to use an opamp-based current sink like @KyranF suggested, and use the 'duino's output to control the reference voltage through a pot.  That way, you still have some adjustability (the range is determined by the sense resistor, specific value within that range by the pot), you can still turn it on/off, and the startup/shutdown behavior is more predictable.

Comment: Wire the (+) input of the opamp to the reference, (-) input to the top of the sense resistor, and the output to the base/gate of the transistor (no resistor needed).  Load current goes from (+) supply, through the laser, transistor, sense resistor, to ground, in that order.  The opamp does whatever it has to with the transistor to match the sense voltage to the reference voltage, thus creating a known current through the sense resistor and therefore the load.

Comment: And like @George said, don't use any more voltage than you have to.  Any extra will be eaten up by the current source/sink and wasted as heat.  You do need some extra, just to guarantee that it always works, but usually not 12V for a 2V laser diode.  With the appropriate sense resistor, you can probably do it with 5V, provided that it can give you 2A.

Comment: Converted my previous comments to an answer.

Answer (score 6):

You are likely to be better off using a MOSFET than a BJT.

We typically assume a BJT will have on the order of 0.2 V between collector and emitter in saturation. With 1 A collector current, that means 200 mW of power dissipation in the transistor.

MOSFET's drain-source channels on the other hand act a lot more like low-value resistors when fully switched.

Going to On Semi, I found several dozen available FETs with channel resistance (r<sub>DS</sub>(on)) below 50 milliohms for gate voltage of 4.5 V and current handling capability above 1.5 A. With this level of on resistance, the power dissipation is reduced to ~50 mW.

Lower power dissipation means a smaller package, probably lower cost, more power available for other functions, and less worry about thermal problems with your laser.

Answer (score 5):

I'd much rather do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsoLNV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The opamp does whatever it has to to keep its (+) and (-) inputs equal.  This makes the voltage across R1 equal to the voltage from R2, which is adjustable between 0-5V when on and 0V when off.  Constant voltage across a constant resistance equals constant current through that resistance.

The only place for that current to come from is through the laser, via the transistor, hence a constant current sink that can be turned on/off via software.  If you wanted, you could add an RC lowpass filter between a PWM output pin and the (+) input (keep the pot though) and also control the brightness via software.  Just make sure that your PWM is actually 0-100% and not the 5-10% used for servos.

Do some math and choose R1 so that it by itself will limit the current to something a bit higher than you're comfortable with, but won't blow up the laser in case the transistor fails short-circuit, or if you adjust it too high, etc.  Then set R2 to provide the same voltage that should be across R1 when drawing the desired current.  Then add the appropriate heatsink(s), and you're done.

Comment: nice job! The point about selecting R1 to be something that is likely to 'fail safe'er than using a normally very low ohm sense resistor is a good one. The op-amp can be given gain through a pot + feedback resistor. In fact a custom PCB will have room for a digital pot with 255 steps over I2C, or indeed a simple SPI/I2C Digital to Analog Converter peripheral can use used to set the "power" of the laser rather than fancy PWM magic. Of course the PWM is fine for LEDs and Lasers, and perhaps the OP can use the PWM for modulation at 32KHz or somethhing.

Comment: Hmm that's OK, but the current depends on the (digital) output voltage of the arduino.. maybe not the most stable source.  (I've done a switched reference type thing.)  Add some R (1k-10k) in the inverting input, and typically you'll need some fast feedback around the opamp ~10-100pF from out to inverting input.

Comment: @KyranF If you lowpass a PWM signal, you get a DAC.  All you need is an R, a C, and a PWM frequency that is much higher than the RC filter's cutoff.  Seems simple enough to me.  It'll have a significant output impedance, but for this purpose, that's okay.

Comment: A proper DAC chip is better though if you want consistency, surely? Theoretically yes, the RC circuit will work but who knows, given temperature and tolerance etc.

Comment: It's no more consistent than the supply voltage, no matter what you use.  Some parts use a separate reference for that, but it only shifts the problem to something else that *might* be easier to work with, doesn't solve it by itself.  For a lowpassed PWM DAC, the output as a percentage of the supply voltage is determined only by the duty cycle.  RC tolerances and temperatures only change the cutoff frequency, which doesn't matter if it's already much lower than the PWM and much higher than the desired response time of the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely way better off (function wise and cost wise) using something like and LED driver eg. [LM3414](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3414.pdf) with PWM input, or if you want to keep it basic you can use a [DLD101](http://diodes.com/datasheets/ds32007.pdf), which is a MOSFET and matching BJT.  With that you can drop the LM338, 1N4007, and heavyweight resistors.

What frequency are you planning on switching the diode on/off at?  Both of the above will work well at < 50kHz.

Pretty sure that you will toast your potentiometer at low resistances, regardless if it is 5W.

Comment: Good point about toasting the pot.  They should be derated by the amount of track actually used.  If 25% of the track is shorted or left hanging in the breeze, then you only have 75% of the rated power.  This is a function of the mechanical position, regardless of the taper (linear, audio, etc.).